# how can i convert string with numbers into array in php?

Tags: php

I have string:  "33a49bc12d" and i want this array 0 => 33 , 1=>a , 2=>49, 3=>bc, 4=>12, 5=>d. This is out of my skill. Could you help me? Thx

Comment: What are the rules that govern where your string is to be split?

Comment: @Clive seems to be the boundary of numbers and alphabets

Comment: @AlvinWong Yep could be, or could be an incorrect attempt to get pairs of hex numbers out of the string. Worth checking I think

Comment: What about symbols and capital letters , are your strings going to contain any of those? or is this the only case that you are interested on?

Comment: Please conduct [some prior research](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20split%20string%20into%20numbers%20and%20letters) at least; one of the regex/preg_match_all answers will do.

Comment: @mario I understand you could be a big fan of regex, but problems like this don't really need regex. Especially a bad idea to suggest to beginners. [Now you have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: @AlvinWong Sure one could write ten lines of manual string traversing and matching in PHP. But one line of regex seems more appealing. In trivial cases like this anyway. But true, while it might be the right tool for the job, it's not necessarily the right advise to newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
<?php
$text = "33a49bc12d";
preg_match_all("/([\d]+|[a-z]+)/i", $text, $out);
print_r($out[0]);
?> 

Array
(
    [0] => 33
    [1] => a
    [2] => 49
    [3] => bc
    [4] => 12
    [5] => d
)
```

Comment: Thx, i tryed preg_match_all before, but not with succes